# How does UIScrollView like scrolling work?

Tags: uikit, uiscrollview, velocity, interpolation

in my opinion the iPhone has a big advantage to other smartphones because of its intuitive, smooth and good feeling scrolling components in UIKit. I want to implement a simple game with UIKit which uses this kind of scrolling, but i can't use UIScrollView because it isn't customizable enough.

I tried to implement this scrolling myself and tried two different approaches:

1. I used a UIPanGestureRecognizer und moved the bounds of my custom control according to the translation the recognizer delivers me. In order to get this smooth scrolling after lifting my finger during the movement I start an animation. I use the velocity the recognizer gives me and a fixed time in order to calculate how far it should scroll after I lifted my finger. I tryed a linear movement and a ease-out movement, but both looks strange. (more later on that)
2. I use OnTouchMoved and OnTouchEnded to implement the scrolling. In OnTouchMove I move the bounds according to the movment of the finger. While the finger moves I calculate the difference in location and time of the current and last touch in order to calculate a velocity myself. When the finger lifts I start an animation in OnTouchEnded like in 1. but I use my self-calculated velocity instead.

Both approaches are not giving me the results I want. After lifting my finger, the scrolling is not smoothly continued. There seems to be a (sharp) bend in the celocity curve.

Has anyone an idea how apple does this smooth scrolling? My current guess is that my interpolation with two really close points is to inaccurate and doesn't take the current acceleration into account.

Thx for your thoughts!
Kie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you add a UIScrollView as handle on top of your view, without visible content. Then you can use the UIScrollViewDelegate methods to update your real view on certain actions. For example: if you capture the scrolling of the UIScrollView using scrollViewDidScroll: , you can update your visible view with the offset of the scrollview. You can use the scrollViewWillEndDragging: to start synchronizing the main view with the scrollview, and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating to stop synchronizing.

I use the same approach to scroll the background of my Animix app. It has an invisible scrollview at the bottom, to give the user the feeling he can drag the grass to the left and right to move the background.